# Can Requested Uri which is used in mobile application be traced

Tags: android, security, http, mobile, http-headers

I am developing android applications. So many times I need to send requests to my server to get some information in JSON format.

My Request-response traffic is so usual now, but I wonder that can somebody trace my requested URIs. *It's so important that sb may block my traffic and this mean that my application may be blocked too*.

*I send POST requests with header params to reach and get information from the server.*

**Is it possible to trace my URIs and params while using GSM network or wifi on mobile device ?**

Regards...

Update:

- Traced by sb to  use my rest service without permission or block my traffic.
- The server are not providing the API using SSL?
- My concern is about   blocking the traffic and "stealing" the information my send/receive?

Comment: I can read you already have some good answers but just a quick hint: Android is indistinguishable from any other WiFi/3G device, so  any security/encryption tutorial, advice or best practices you read about WiFi networks on normal computers are equally applied to Android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your'e sending unencrypted requests, yes, it is traceable and readable. By using SSL you minimize the risk.

In every WiFi it's possible to block certain ports. That means, your requests can be blocked, yes.

Comment: Could you explain in detail or suggest a document about it ? Thanks a lot. (Blocking the traffic --> ddos attacks to server, Now yes, it's possible.  (Because  sb knows the URI) )

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Ok so your connection can be certainly traced/intercepted by your provider (when it comes to GSM/3G connection) or by the provider of the wifi. If the wifi is open (no encryption) practically anyone can intercept and modify the data (Man in the middle attacks are easy on unsecured wifi).

what you can do to prevent this:

1. Use SSL (https) on the server that way the owner/attacker can see the host you're connecting to but not the data. He can still block the destination server, there's nothing you can do about it.
2. Sign your requests with a private key. This will stop most attackers from injecting requests, together with SSL the connection will be as secure as it gets. A determined attacker however can reverse engineer your app to get to the private key and find out how you sign your requests.

Comment: Updated, please check !

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want ask questions use comments.

Comment: sorry about that, anyways I updated the "not an answer" with an answer. Hopefully it will help you get started.